# MVC 5 implicit conversion exists

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I have a repository that I am tring to get a query to pass to a controller.

```
 public ProjectViewModel SearchContractors(string zip)
 {
     var query = (from h in repository.tblHandymen
                  join hc in repository.tblHandyManCoverages on h.handymanID equals hc.handymanID
                  join s in repository.tblServiceRequests on hc.zip equals s.zip
                  where hc.zip == zip
                  where h.handymanID == hc.handymanID
                  where h.status == "Active"
                  select h
                  );
     ProjectViewModel model = new ProjectViewModel
     {
         ContractorSearch = query.AsEnumerable()                                 
     };

     return model;
 }
```

Where I am stuck is here

```
ProjectViewModel model = new ProjectViewModel
{
    ContractorSearch = query.AsEnumerable()                                 
};
```

The error is an implicit conversion exists. Tried several things. Nothing working.

Comment: What's the type of `ContractorSearch`?

Comment: public IEnumerable<ProjectContractorSearchViewModel> ContractorSearch { get; set; }

Comment: My suggestion is, Do not mix your data access code in your view models. It totally defeats the purpose of view models and separation of concern.

Comment: My view model doesn't have data access code. Not sure what you mean.

Comment: Your query is not returning a collection of `ProjectContractorSearchViewModel`. You need to project the data to the type - `var query = (....).Select(x => new ProjectContractorSearchViewModel{ someProperty = x.someValue, ...etc });`

Comment: @StephenMuecke that works. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query is not returning a collection of `ProjectContractorSearchViewModel` objects (its returning a collection of `tblHandymen`). You need to project the results to typeof `ProjectContractorSearchViewModel`

```
var query = (from h in repository.tblHandymen
             .....
            ).Select(x => new ProjectContractorSearchViewModel
            {
                someProperty = x.someProperty,
                anotherProperty = x.anotherProperty,
                ....
            });
ProjectViewModel model = new ProjectViewModel
{
    ContractorSearch = query.AsEnumerable()                            
};
return model;
```